# Start PsSession on windows load in hta

Tags: powershell, vbscript, hta, powershell-remoting, exchange-management-shell

I have a 500+ lines vb script. It is being used by HR to set some AD attributes. Now I need to use Set-UserPhoto cmdlet of Exchange Powershell Management tools. I don't want to rewrite all script in powershell. On script startup, I want to call Exchange Powershell, which loads very slow. And then during script call Set-UserPhoto.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Sub window_onload
command = "powershell.exe –ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command ""$session = New-PSSession -configurationname Microsoft.Exchange -connectionuri http://mail/powershell; Import-PSSession $session -CommandName set-userphoto"""
objShell.run command,1,true
End Sub
.
.
Sub Save_button
command2 = "powershell.exe –ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command ""Set-UserPhoto -Identity User -PictureData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('D:\pictures\user.jpg')) -Confirm:$false"""
objShell.run command2,1,true
End Sub
```

On pressing Save button, it doesn't recognize Set-UserPhoto cmdlet. How to keep first powershell session from first command till the end of script?

Comment: You are losing PSSession that way and cmdlet does not recognize. You could try to dublicate new-pssession code part for Save_button. -command ""$session = New-PSSession -configurationname Microsoft.Exchange -connectionuri http://mail/powershell; Import-PSSession $session -CommandName set-userphoto; Set-UserPhoto -Identity User -PictureData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('D:\pictures\user.jpg')) -Confirm:$false"""

Comment: Import-PSSession is very slow procedure. It takes up to 30 seconds. So idea is to call it only once on windows load. So then user can change several user photos in this session.